# Minio unable to access bucket in another aws account

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I have an IAM user in account A with keys set up (xxx) and I wish to access a bucket in account B. On the aws cli, I can run `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx aws s3api head-bucket --bucket account-b-bucket` (and list objects, etc) and it works just fine (I set up a bucket policy and proper iam policy, so this is expected).

I have a minio server running with those access keys passed as minion access keys. If I start up the minio client (I use python) and run `client.bucket_exists("some-bucket-in-account-a")` it works. However, `client.bucket_exists("account-b-bucket")` returns `False`.

I tried this out for buckets in both us-east-1 and us-west-2, and it does not work.

What else is required for minio to access a bucket in another aws account?

Note that I start my minio client with the endpoint of `s3.amazonaws.com` it does work, but I want to point the minio client to my running minio instance like `my-minio.my-site.com`.